# Scheduled reminders after membership end date not being sent

Tags: civimember, email, scheduled-reminders, mailing

I'm using CIVI CRM with WordPress (CIVI version 5.22.1)

I'm testing scheduled reminders for memberships by having a test user sign up to a membership and pay using PayPal Sandbox (not recurring payment).

The membership is set to last for 2 days.

A reminder email is set to send 1 day BEFORE membership end date. This email is sent successfully and recorded as an activity in the user profile.

A reminder email is set to send 2 days AFTER membership end date. This email is NOT sent but it is recorded as an activity in the user profile.

There's no evidence of the emails being rejected by the receiving email server or being sent to spam folders in either the cpanel webmail accounts or gmail accounts used during the tests.

The reminders are not set to repeat.

Anyone have any ideas why the first reminder email is successfully sent and received but not the second?

I've tested this many times (at least 6 times) and the result is always the same.

[image]
(The image attached shows that all emails are still recorded as activities whether sent tor not.)

Comment: it may be unrelated by curious why an Activity would be created with no name in 'Added by' or 'With'

Comment: oh maybe you have hidden those in screenshot for privacy reasons

Comment: also wondering if our Transactional Email extension might help you get more clues if you don't yet have it on the site: https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional

Comment: Hello, yes sorry, I did hide the Added by. Not sure your extension would fix my issue because the 2nd reminder email is never being sent so it's not even possible for them to bounce, or for clicks to be tracked tracked. Also Civi CRM already adds an activity (even though the 2nd email is not sent).

Comment: @Monica did you manage to check PHP error - I had a client how add similar issue with the template which was not sending the email to go out - End of the day the issue was with the message template

Comment: Hello,Thank you. I couldn't find where any errors were being logged for this issue, but I will try choosing a different template to see if that works.